# OpenConnect causing problems with httpd service

Tags: php, vpn, http, httpd, openconnect

My httpd service was working properly, however whenever using OpenConnect through the box I can no longer connect to the box's webserver, it's giving me a 522 timeout error.  Maybe I'm going about this wrong but I plan on accessing a page (that requires vpn access to view) via my php script in my web daemon.  How would I go about fixing this?

Connecting with: openconnect -s /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script https://example.com/ --authgroup=A-RSA --user=example -b

I can connect fine, then view files within the VPN fine, I can view outside of the VPN all fine, the only issue is when someone is accessing any site on this box, they all return a 522 connection timeout error.

Comment: This could be caused by any number of different misconfigurations.  You haven't given enough information to figure out which one it might be.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this isn't helpful either, I'll add to my post